# How did they come up with this expansion?

Tags: real-analysis

In [Probability density function of the $t$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution#Probability_density_function), this series expansion was presented:

[image]

where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function, and  $\nu$ is a positive integer.

Anybody please thoroughly explain to me how this expansion was derived...

Comment: Have you checked [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties] ? There the needed properties of the Gamma function  are presented.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Andreas in the comments, use recursively the property
$$\Gamma (x+1) = x \Gamma (x)$$